# Entity Framework Change Tracking (Read Only) query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Just wanted peoples opinions on a scenario:

Would it be more efficient to:

1. Select a record with change tracking turned off and then if it needs to be updated reattach the object to the context for update?

   - or -
2. Select a record with change tracking turned on just in case the record needs to be updated?

Or is this trivial?

My scenario is that we have a health check routine that does a select on a table every 10 seconds and very rarely needs to be updated (Only updates the record if a new version has been deployed). So should we do the health check with change tracking turned off turned on?

Comment: may be this could help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your use case, I think `No-tracking` queries will give `big performance boost` to your app.

So you can do that using `AsNoTracking()`

```
using (var context = new HelthContext())
{
    var patients = context.Patients.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

If you have an `entity` that you know `already exists` in the database but which is `not currently being tracked` by the `context` then you can tell the `context` to track the entity using the `Attach` method on `DbSet` as shown below.

```
var existingPatient = new Patient { Id = 1, Name = "Patient 1" }; 

using (var context = new HelthContext()) 
{ 
    context.Patients.Attach(existingPatient ); 

    // Do some more work...  

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

**Reference :** [**Entity states and SaveChanges**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: same approach i use, but I add this line after attach, `context.Entry(existingPatient).State = EntityState.Modified;` , I think this is required to tell the context that this data is for update and not insert, right?

Comment: that use case is different.that is ,If you have an `entity` that you know already exists in the database but to `which changes` may have been made then you can tell the `context to attach` the entity and `set its state to Modified`. i.e. `Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context`. @HadiHassan

Comment: I have added good **Reference** above.you too can see that :) @HadiHassan